# I am making OCR Reader Application. When I create the PDF of generated text, it is not saved as I want. There is one problem in the while loop

Tags: java, android

To save this PDF I have added a **while loop** where the last letter has added a specific number from 0 to n in parentheses. When I save the first PDF it is saved as `myPDFfile.pdf` then the second pdf will be saved as `myPDFFile(1).pdf` but when I save the third pdf it will be saved as `myPDFFile(1)(1).pdf`  
but I want this pdf to save as `myPDFfile(2).pdf`.

```
import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;

    private CameraSource cameraSource;
    private TextRecognizer textRecognizer;
    Button button;

    private TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    private String stringResult = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        button = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{CAMERA}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        cameraSource.release();
    }

    private void textRecognizer() {
        textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecognizer)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .build();

        surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        Context context = this;
        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                        return;
                    }
                    cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });
    }

    private void capture() {
        textRecognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {
            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {

                SparseArray<TextBlock> sparseArray = detections.getDetectedItems();
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 0; i < sparseArray.size(); ++i) {
                    TextBlock textBlock = sparseArray.valueAt(i);
                    if (textBlock != null && textBlock.getValue() != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(textBlock.getValue() + " ");
                    }
                }

                final String stringText = stringBuilder.toString();

                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        stringResult = stringText;
                        resultObtained();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private void resultObtained() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(stringResult);
        textToSpeech.speak(stringResult, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
    }

    public void buttonStart(View view) {
        setContentView(R.layout.surface);
        Button capture = findViewById(R.id.capture);
        capture.setOnClickListener(v -> capture());
        textRecognizer();
    }

    public void createMyPDF(View view) {

        PdfDocument myPdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo myPageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(300, 600, 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page myPage = myPdfDocument.startPage(myPageInfo);

        Paint myPaint = new Paint();
        String myString = textView.getText().toString();
        int x = 10, y = 25;

        for (String line : myString.split("\n")) {
            myPage.getCanvas().drawText(line, x, y, myPaint);
            y += myPaint.descent() - myPaint.ascent();
        }
        myPdfDocument.finishPage(myPage);


        String myFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myPDFFile.pdf";

        File myFile = new File(myFilePath);
        while (myFile.exists()) {
            int i = 0;
            i++;
            myFile = new File(myFile.toString().replace("myPDFFile", "myPDFFile (" + i + ")"));

        }

            try {
                myPdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(myFile));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                textView.setText("ERROR");
            }

            myPdfDocument.close();
        }

    public void onPause() {
        if (textToSpeech != null) {
            textToSpeech.stop();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

XML Code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="OCR READER FOR VISUALLY IMPARED PEOPLES"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="407dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:onClick="buttonStart"
        android:text="Click here"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:onClick="createMyPDF"
        android:text="Create PDF"
        android:textSize="20dp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

surface.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="378dp"
        android:layout_height="628dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/capture"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:text="Capture"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can someone give me the hint

Comment: myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myPDFFile(" + i + ").pdf");

Comment: But where do I have to add this.

Comment: No adding. Replace your line with this one.

Comment: It not works it makes only two pdfs `myPDFFile.pdf` and `myPDFFile(1).pdf` after that app will closed

Comment: `int i = 0;` Put that before the while loop. Not in it.

Comment: great job bro. it works.